# How to use CORS in ASP.NET Web API SelfHost applications?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I'am trying to use ASP.NET Web API Selfhosted application with CORS, but getting an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5555/api/product. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add class

```
public class CustomHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

and register it in configuration

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:5555");    
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomHeaderHandler());
```

Comment: @Nerve that didn't work out for me, I still get, "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1125/api/Home/Data/somestring No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1025' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 2):

The WebAPIContrib project has a simple Cors [MessageHandler](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/MessageHandlers/SimpleCorsHandler.cs).  Or if you are looking for more sophisticated solution, the [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](http://thinktecture.github.io/) project has CORS support.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi By now CORS support is baked in Web API too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that by installing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package from [**Nuget**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors).

This will allow your API to enable `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)`. You can do it like:

```
 var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(_baseAddress);
 config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```